# View activity stack in Android

Tags: android, debugging, android-activity, stack

Is it possible to view the activity stack in Android for debugging purposes?

Comment: this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442713/view-the-tasks-activity-stack

Answer (score 136, accepted):

To display the activity stack, run the following command :

```
adb shell dumpsys activity activities
```

Comment: and if you do `adb shell dumpsys activity activities` you'll get a smaller amount of info which includes the running tasks, activities and recent tasks.

Comment: Building off this, this piped command is quite handy (from another SO thread)
`adb shell dumpsys activity | grep -i run`

Comment: adb shell dumpsys activity | grep -i 'run' | grep -i 'com.example.package'

Comment: is there a way to watch it live and not a snapshot? Things are happening too fast...

Comment: @Nathan H - assuming you are on linux, you can use the watch command: `watch -n 1 "adb shell dumpsys activity | grep -i com.yourapp"`

Comment: where do i run this command?

Comment: @VikasPandey The Terminal / Console. Wherever you would typically run `adb` commands.