# How does android:noHistory="true" work?

Tags: android

Lets say I have a base activity with a menu, when I click on menu item A, it goes to activity A. I open the menu again, and go to B. From B I go back to A, and back and fourth like this for a while.

So the stack would be A, B, A, B, A, B, ....
And when I hit the back button, it goes backwards through the stack as expected.

However lets say I don't want this functionality, so I add to my manifest, `android:noHistory="true"`. So when I hit the back button it exits the application instead of going though the stack.

Now the illusion makes it seem, lets say if I'm in activity A, I use the menu and go to activity B, the stack would just be B, because I can't go back to A.

But, when using `noHistory="true"`, does the true stack of A, B, A, B, A, B exist? Rather, is every call to an activity by using the menu instantiating a new copy of that activity, but the user can't see it? Would this be causing resource issues?

Or when `noHistory="false"`, does the back button just call something like `startAcitvity(intent)` again or is it going through each new copy that was instantiated?

I'm concerned with resource issues and not slowing down a users android device.

Comment: You can test it yourself, see this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4387875/view-activity-stack-in-android

Answer (score 53, accepted):

From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) about `noHistory`:

> A value of "true" means that the activity will not leave a historical trace. It will not remain in the activity stack for the task, so the user will not be able to return to it.

Regarding your question:

> does the true stack of A, B, A, B, A, B exist?

The docs would indicate no.

> I'm concerned with resource issues and not slowing down a users android device.

You really don't need to worry about this. The OS should handle the cleanup of activities when memory is getting low.  Its more likely that poor use of bitmaps or logic in your activities will result in performance slowdowns.

Answer (score 10):

android:noHistory=“true” works :-

Let suppose you have opened "your app".

You are on homepage Activity now,

After it you go to the another(second) activity.Here from second activity you press the home button of mobile device or open the some other application.

Now again if you open "your app" it will go to the homepage of app instead of going to the activity which one you left the app(i.e.second activity).

Comment: Add this line to your Manifest file after <activity:  android:excludeFromRecents="true"  this will force your app seems like never ever turned on. A little bit bad decision I know, but if you need this, this code *somehow* works.

Comment: @Bay Why would you need this? What problem are you trying to solve? I think Raghav's answer is clear and answers the original question

Answer (score 0):

I had few fragments in my app and it seemed difficult to get out to the home screen by pressing back button without entering  Launcher Activity of my app. I used android:noHistory="true" in the manifest of the launcher Activity of my app and the problem gets solved now.

Comment: this is not right way to do that. you need to maintain fragment backstack

Comment: This answer may seem "working" only just when user pressed back button to exit the app, when user pressed home button, it won't solve the issue.