# Android: return to the Application Home Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, return

I am trying to use the next code to return back to the My Application Home Activity from the stack of my application:

```
protected void goHome(boolean offlineMode) {
    final Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
...
}
```

But in this case all other applications activities on the top will be closed too.
Is it possible to close activities only of my application in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the work.

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, HomeActivity.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

Comment: I use old sdk and don't have Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK

Answer (score 1):

You can also implement this from your **AndroidManifest.xml** file, just adding

```
android:noHistory="true"
```

attribute in those `<activity>` you want (eg. HomeActivity)

see here is the sample code of manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.rdc.helloWorld"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".HelloWorldActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:noHistory="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

so when you click back button on Home Activity screen, it will clear history of this screen only

You may like read about noHistory tag details,

[**How does android:noHistory=“true” work?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11836080/how-does-androidnohistory-true-work)