# How to handle status bar notification?

Tags: android, notifications

I have three screens like login,second and third. Based on my conditions i generate a status bar notification. If user click the notification i want to show third screen. It is working fine. But when i restart the app directly third screen is coming. I want to display third screen when notification is clicked. Other wise my first screen should be the login page.

I can display notification by using the following code

```
public void showNotification() 
    {
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "A New Message!", System.currentTimeMillis());


    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(Preferences.this,PendingOffers.class);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(Preferences.this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

    notification.setLatestEventInfo(Preferences.this,"sample notification", "notificationMessage", pendingIntent);

    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    notificationManager.notify(0, notification); 
};
```

Comment: Please put Some Code about how you are calling third screen when user click on Notification. So we can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set flag for intent,
eg

> FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY

Reference : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY
Check other flags too.

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, some.class)
intent.putExtra("yourpackage.notifyId", id);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1, intent, 0);
```

for more information check this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals.html)

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are asking doesn't really relate to the notification you are using. The user is returned to the third `Activity` in you application, because when your application isn't really stopped, but just paused in the background, the user is per default brought back to the last activity he viewed when the launcher icon is clicked again.

There are multiple solutions to this problem, depending on your situation. if the user should never return to the third `Activity`, you can set `android:noHistory=“true”` in your manifest for that activity, see here: [How does android:noHistory=“true” work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11836080/how-does-androidnohistory-true-work)

If only logged-in users should be able to return to the third `Activity`, you could just store if the user is logged in in the `SharedPreferences`. When the third `Activity` starts, you check that value and redirect the user to the Login-Activity using the flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` for your `Intent`. This will clear all `Activities` from the stack after your Login-Activity was executed the last time.