# How to set the limit of activities in back stack in Android?

Tags: android, performance

In the app that I am making, there are 12 different activities linked to the main page. All of them are independent of each other. I want the previous activities removed from the back stack so that the app takes less memory.
I have managed to have single instance of each activity by using

```
android:launchMode = "singleInstance"
```

But still when these activities are started from the main page, 12 different pages go in the back stack and app crashes.
What is the work-around?

Comment: Try adding Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
this flag when you go from one activity another......this thing you can define in manifest as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like android:noHistory="true" would be the solution for you.

> A value of "true" means that the activity will not leave a historical
>   trace. It will not remain in the activity stack for the task, so the
>   user will not be able to return to it.

[How does android:noHistory="true" work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11836080/how-does-androidnohistory-true-work)

Comment: `android:noHistory = "true" `
Doesn't seem to work very well. I mean the memory allocated is still rising for opening activities even. If I switch between two activities a couple of times, the memory keeps on rising (~20MB in each activity call) until the app crashes at 180MB. If there is noHistory of activities in backstack this shouldn't be happening.

Answer (score 0):

when you go back start the MainActivty,call this on backpress on 12 activitys.

```
Intent intent  = new Intent(youeActivity.this,MainActivity.class); 
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);      
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

manofest add this one

```
android:excludeFromRecents="true"
```