# How can I view task stacks of Android application?

Tags: android

I want to view current tasks with their activity stacks of android application. What tool should I use?

Comment: possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442713/view-the-tasks-activity-stack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `adb shell dumpsys activity` to view the activity stack.

You can then search for "Hist" to see just the Activity stack, e.g.

```
Hist #11: HistoryRecord{40c0c018 com.mypackage/com.mypackage.ActivityB}
Hist #10: HistoryRecord{40d27af0 com.mypackage/com.mypackage.ActivityA}
Hist #9: HistoryRecord{40d31368 com.mypackage/com.mypackage.LoginActivity}
Hist #8: HistoryRecord{40db2430 com.mypackage/com.mypackage.MainActivity}
Hist #7: HistoryRecord{40c2a978 com.mypackage/com.mypackage.LoginActivity}
Hist #6: HistoryRecord{40bf6008 com.mypackage/com.mypackage.LoginActivity}
Hist #5: HistoryRecord{40542d58 com.htc.launcher/.Launcher}
```

Comment: It's bad that there is no gui method =(((