# How to see the activity stack in debug?

Tags: android, activity-stack

I have a problem that one of my activities is popping out after *I think* I finished it.

Is there a way to see the stack of the activities?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1-You can use  `Hierarchy Viewer` within `Eclipse`.You can see  all connected devices and emulators and the `activity stack`. And in addition in the tree view you can see much more information about the view itself:
[image]

2-From the `command line`, you can use this: `adb shell dumpsys activity`.This asks the activity manager to print a dump of its current state. The first part of that is the complete activity history, organized by task.
You can see more details [`here`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442713/view-the-tasks-activity-stack).

Comment: Thanks but I had a problem seeing the data on Eclipse's 'Windows' view. Here are the errors: [2012-07-08 16:48:06 - hierarchyviewer]Unable to get view server version from device 0149A91D0F01C00D
[2012-07-08 16:48:06 - hierarchyviewer]Unable to get view server protocol version from device 0149A91D0F01C00D
[2012-07-08 16:48:08 - hierarchyviewer]Unable to debug device 0149A91D0F01C00D

Comment: I see the same "Unable to get view server protocol version from device" error. Anyone know of a fix for this?

Comment: In case somebody is lost in the output of `dumpsys`, maybe searching for the following string might help you: `Task display areas in top down Z order`. This section shows history of ordered activities.