# Start Activity Android with class name

Tags: android, android-activity, classname

I am using Following Code to start setting I want to launch the setting activity which is started by android ins

```
PackageList allowedAppsPackageName=CallHelper.Ds.getPackageList();
            PackageManager manager = CallDetectService.packageManager;
            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
            mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

        final List<ResolveInfo> apps = manager.queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);
        Collections.sort(apps, new ResolveInfo.DisplayNameComparator(manager));
        final int count = apps.size();
        ResolveInfo info=new ResolveInfo();;
        GridViewAppList.clear();

                 for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) 
                 {

                        info= apps.get(i);
                        if(info.activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName.contains("setting"))
                            break;

                 }
                ApplicationInfo application = new ApplicationInfo();

                application.title = info.loadLabel(manager);
                application.setActivity(new ComponentName(
                        packageName,
                        info.activityInfo.name),
                        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
                application.icon = info.activityInfo.loadIcon(manager);
                application.packagename=packageName;
                Log.i("PKG", application.packagename+" "+packageName+" "+info.activityInfo.name);
                GridViewAppList.add(application);
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use this snippet to open `Settings` Activity :

```
Intent intent=new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.Settings"));
startActivity(intent);
```

If you do not know what Activity you have to open,you can find it's name and it's package name as I mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11373194/1043882).

Comment: This is k if i know the class name but what if I dont know  ?

Answer (score 0):

There are many action constants in the [`Settings`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html) class that can be used to create an intent that will start an activity for the provided sub-Setting or simply launch the Settings app depending on the action.

For example:

```
intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS); // ACTION_SETTINGS will start the Settings app

intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS); // ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS will show the WiFi settings
```