# How to start an activity/layout of an application from the library inside that same application

Tags: java, android

I have a sample application(Ex:MainApplication) and added into that a library as module dependency(LoginInvokeApplication).

I'm able to access the resources of library from the application.

My question is how can I access the class name and layout of an activity in the application inside my library. I couldn't add the application's package name/application's activity name in library's manifest also.

Help me with some guidance to access resources & classes in my library's activity

Comment: this is the worst architectural deciscion I ever seen

Comment: There is a need for me to do. Because I have all my common features in my library. So, once done inheriting a feature and gets success I must move on to my activity of main application

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18160918/start-activity-android-with-class-name

Comment: But I'm in need to access that activity's layout from my library activity.

Comment: @Override
    public void setContentView(@LayoutRes int layoutResID) {
        if (sharedpreferences.contains("username") && sharedpreferences.contains("password")) {
       super.setContentView(com.example.devika.Mainapplication.MainActivity.R.layout.client_main);
        }
        else {
            super.setContentView(R.layout.activity_logininvoke);
            initializeViews();
        }
    }

Comment: Is there any way to access its layout?

Comment: you can only use reflection to get a hold on a class or static resource like layout, which is not available at compile time of your library. `intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("your.pkg", "your.pkg.YourClass"));` is a short-cut to get an activity