# Is it possible to view the contents of Android's back stack?

Tags: android

I am looking for a tool (perhaps an Eclipse plugin) that can give me some visibility into Android's back stack.  I am trying to find my way around an application that I inherited.  I frequently navigate to a screen, then try to determine what activity is running.  I have the source code, so I can always answer this question, but it is not always quick and easy.

It would be great if in DDMS I could see an indication of what activity is active.  It would be even better if I could view the entire contents of the back stack, or at least those activies in my process.  That would give me some nice visibility into what Android is doing.

I realize that there are permission issues that would/should prevent this on an actual device, but I would be fine if this simply worked with the emulator.

Does anyone know of a tool or an approach that could help with this?

Comment: Read the [developers SDK on the lifecycle of the activities](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html), then, use the source luke, read it, breathe it, study it, modify it by sprinkling **Log.d(TAG, "HERE")** in the lifecycle of activities functions, that's how you'll get to know where you are!

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I am quite familiar with activity lifecycle and have already put the Log statements in, which did help.  I was however hoping for a more general, less intrusive approach that potentially gave me visibility beyond my app.

Comment: adb is your friend: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442713/view-the-tasks-activity-stack

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar question like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442713/view-the-tasks-activity-stack/7172633#7172633) and became quite popular.

Learning from that question, you can use this command in the adb shell :`dumpsys activity`. This will dump the current state of the activity manager. By digging into it, you can get the list of tasks and activities that are in the back-stack. According to [techterms](https://techterms.com/definition/stack), it is not advisable for any programmer to get the pieces in the middle of the stack(which breaks the purpose of stack). So there will not a any direct way you can get the full view of the backstack.

Mainly `dumpsys activity` dumps what happened since the start of the activity manager. So it all starts with an empty back-stack and fills up later. So you can see what is pushed and what is popped from the stack to get the state of current stack.