# Activities stack android - back from a URI launched pdf doesnt return to correct activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I am going out of my mind trying to work out why one of my activities is not working correctly with the stack.back button.

Activity Brain is launched when the user presses an image button in Main activity, this works fine and the back button behaves as expected from Brain (ie it returns to main activity as expected).

Within brain i want to launch a PDF based on which image button the user presses, I am doing this via URI with the code below, the PDF loads fine, but when back is pressed within acrobat the app returns to Main activity and not the brain which is not the behaviour i want (or expected).  I have read the app developers guide and tried all options with Intent Flag_activity (i think) but have not been able to fix the back button behaviour.  I have tried linking to different PDFs (in case it was something random in acrobat) but the app behaves the same, always going back to main and not the brain that I want.

I am using Imagebuttons to allow the user to select the pdfs and the code below is calling the URI / intent to display the pdf.  I have left in 2 of the Intent.Flags I have tried and had no luck with for amplification, I had expected Intent.Flag_Activity_Clear_Top to work, but i must have missed something.

Brain activity is called from main using the following onClick code

```
 if (v==bbrain) {
                    Intent startbrain = new Intent(Main.this, Brain.class); //this is the Brain chooser
                    startActivity(startbrain);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_from_left_enter, R.anim.pull_out_to_left_exit);
                    }
```

Then brain activity java looks like this:

```
public void onClick(View v) {

            if (v==bhome); {
            Intent starthome = new Intent(Brain.this, Main.class); //this is main screen
            startActivity(starthome);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.zoom_enter, R.anim.zoom_exit);
            }

            if (v==babouttest){
                Intent start1gp = new Intent(Brain.this, AboutScreen.class); //this is 1gp lesson
                startActivity(start1gp);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_from_left_enter, R.anim.pull_out_to_left_exit);
            }

            if (v==imagepetro) {
                File file = new File("/sdcard/documents/1.pdf");
                  if (file.exists()) {
                        Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                        try {
                            startActivity(intent);
                            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.zoom_enter, R.anim.zoom_exit);
                        } 
                        catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {

                        }
                  }
            }   //end of load

 if (v==imagesteam) {
                File file = new File("/sdcard/documents/2.pdf");
                  if (file.exists()) {
                        Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

                        try {
                            startActivity(intent);
                            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.zoom_enter, R.anim.zoom_exit);
                        } 
                        catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {

                        }
                  }
            }   //end of load

   }

  //menu inflator bits
          @Override
            public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_brain, menu);
                return true;
            }  

            @Override
            public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case android.R.id.home:
                        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
                        return true;
                }
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }

}
```

I am not sure if i have missed something elsewhere when writing this app?  Below is the brain and main activity sections out of the manifest if that makes any difference

```
   <activity
        android:name=".Main"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <!-- <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> -->
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
 <activity
        android:name=".Brain"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_brain"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.trainer.Main" />
    </activity>
```

I am totally out of ideas why this code isnt working, i am launching PDFs from elsewhere in other activities and the URI way has worked fine, I am missing something but hopefully a fresh pair of eyes will spot what I cant!

Hopefully I have provided enough detail, if not please let me know what I should include.  Thanks for any help, Andy

Comment: I Guess that cause of problem is FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP flag. look at the android docs: `If set, and the activity being launched is already running in the current task, then instead of launching a new instance of that activity, all of the other activities on top of it will be closed and this Intent will be delivered to the (now on top) old activity as a new Intent.`

Comment: continue: `For example, consider a task consisting of the activities: A, B, C, D. If D calls startActivity() with an Intent that resolves to the component of activity B, then C and D will be finished and B receive the given Intent, resulting in the stack now being: A, B.`

Comment: I have tried commenting out the Flag_Activity_Clear_Top and the behaviour is the same though??  Also, the way i read the docs then the brain activity (already running in the task) then the pdf shouldnt be making any call to Main activity through back.  I have clearly mis read this, but I dont understand why with the Flag_activity_Clear_top commented out the back button still goes to Main and not the brain activity?

Comment: Do you finish() Brain Activity?

Comment: i havent called a finish() manually but it is behaving as if the brain activity is closed.

Comment: Remove meta tag in your manifest file and say what happens.

Comment: I have removed them and the behaviour is the same sadly.  (although the app does crash nicely if you use the action bar back button now!).

Answer (score 0):

So following this post here [View the Task's activity stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442713/view-the-tasks-activity-stack)

my activity stack prints out as follows from main to brain activity (correctly)

```
Running activities (most recent first):
  Run #3: ActivityRecord{41cd3948 u0 com.trainer/.Brain}
  Run #2: ActivityRecord{41ca29a0 u0 com.trainer/.Main}
  Run #1: ActivityRecord{41a2c5d8 u0 com.cyanogenmod.trebuchet/.Launcher}
```

so all good so far I think, but when I launch any of the pdfs from the brain activity this is the resultant activity stack:

```
      Run #5: ActivityRecord{4154ca00 u0 com.adobe.reader/.ARViewer}
  Run #4: ActivityRecord{41bcbcf8 u0 com.trainer/.Main}
  Run #3: ActivityRecord{41cd3948 u0 com.trainer/.Brain}
  Run #2: ActivityRecord{41ca29a0 u0 com.trainer/.Main}
  Run #1: ActivityRecord{41a2c5d8 u0 com.cyanogenmod.trebuchet/.Launcher}
```

So for some reason opening the PDF starts another version of the main activity, btu I have no idea at all why this is happening?  Hopefully this means something to someone else?

Thanks for any help that can be offered on this....

Answer (score 0):

So get this, copy and paste all the code from Brain in to a new activity called brain 2 and the app works fine.  No idea why, not a tidy solution but at least it works!  I had tried cleaning the project but it made not difference.  At least its sorted now.