# Android: how many Activities are created by an Application?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-activity, emulation

Hi and thanks for your help,

I have the code of third party application that, I believe, creates more that one Activity and probably more than an instance of the same Activity.

Please on Emulator using Eclipse, how can I understand/monitor which activities are created in the application during its exexution?

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: Ask the original developer who gave you the third part code to explain its flow to you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use command line:

```
adb shell dumpsys activity
```

This command will print activity history in every task. So you can see which activities were created. [Check this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442713/view-the-tasks-activity-stack)

P.S. If you really have source code, why dont you look throught it and find all places where new activity get started? You can add log output at onCreate of every activity... question isn't clear )