# Can we see our stack of activity for my own Android application?

Tags: android

Is there a way to see the stack activity of my own application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is Hierarchy Viewer.
You can see the `Activity` stack in **Hierarchy Viewer**.

Comment: it is saying "ViewServerDevice]Unable to debug device: samsung-gt_i9505-4807291a" :/

Comment: u got Hierarchy Viewer in eclipse?

Comment: so now..whats' the problem?..can u see the activity stack?..just try to run your app and check..

Comment: "HierarchyViewer does not work on user builds (i.e. with devices
available in stores.) This is for security reasons. If HiearchyViewer
was able to work on user builds, any application on your desktop (or
even on the phone in some cases) could potentially get access to
private information (like logins and passwords.)"

Comment: yes i did run, and it wasn't showing. 
Maybe due to that error "Unable to get view server protocol version from device"

Answer (score 3):

type this in the command line:

```
 adb shell dumpsys activity
```

or

```
 adb shell dumpsys activity activities
```

(second one gives a shorter stack)

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2444741/1675954)

Comment: i dont have that command line "adb" on my terminal,ok its on my platform tools dossier

Comment: @Damiii you don't have means you don't know hw to access it or its nt there

Comment: i saw where it is now,and did the command above:
and i'm little confused with all these lines

Comment: @Damiii all those lines are your activity!

Comment: if you add activities at the end of the line you'll get a shorter stack

Comment: hummm, i only see one activity of my application

Comment: @Damiii with the second one? maybe stick with the first if you're just building it

Comment: i did the first one, how do i know if is doing a push or a pop ?

Comment: maybe set alwaysretaintaskstate to true http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#always

Comment: i don't know about the push/pop i'm afraid

Comment: oh :/ i thought i could see the stack activity in real time :)

Comment: http://androidcodeexamples.blogspot.ie/2012/08/multiple-android-activities-in.html